# converting 2 sas datasets to 2 matrixes to perform division and multiply by thousand

Tags: sas

Both the datasets have same number of columns and column names. I stored most of the column names in sorted_cols macro which is basically separated by space. One more additional column exists as ID in both the sas datasets.some of the values in these are null(.) aswell. To convert the datasets to matrix m1 I tried this.

```
proc iml
varNames = {&sorted_col};
use Sashelp.Class(OBS=31);
read all var varNames into m1; 
close Sashelp.Class;
print m[colname=VarNames];
quit;
```

obviously it is throwing errors.
I thought I should mention the dataset somewhere which I dont know where to add.The next step I thought would be easy by (m1/m2)*1000 where m1 and m2 being 2 matrices and storing in a new matrix. May be try to write it back to a dataset.I am prettty much naive in sas.
This is my objective one is the dataset1, two is dataset2 what I want to get is to do division of element1 from dataset2(two) by element 1 of dataset1(one).next do the cumulative adition of the previous answer over the column down.

[image]

Comment: You want to perform elementwise division?

Comment: yes I would need elementwise division

Comment: Do you really need to go to IML (are you doing other things there)?  Elementwise division is perfectly doable in base SAS.

Comment: After this step I would like to get cumulative value for each bucket(id) to plot a graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't particularly difficult to do in base SAS.  Of course, in IML it's even easier, but if you're not familiar with IML there's no particular reason to go into it unless you want to learn it.

This is one way; there are some interesting options using weighting also, but I find this nice and simple and easy to read and understand.  First I initialize `one` and `two`, then do the work.  Edited to reflect your data, and some code changes, particularly to add the running total concept.  PROC MEANS at the bottom is the alternative to the running total - it would only work if you removed the running total (the two lines relating to `tempsums`), as with that in it's summing the running totals, which is not correct.

```
data one;
input (d_201409-d_201412) (:best.);
row_label = _n_-1;
datalines;
3768 7079 6933 8451
3768 7079 6933 8448
3768 7079 6933 8447.4
3768 7079 6933 8447
3768 7079 6933 8447
3768 7079 6933 8445.86667
;;;;
run;

data two;
input (d_201409-d_201412) (:best.);
row_label = _n_-1;
datalines;
. 1 . 1
. 4 . 1
. . . .
. . 1 .
1 . . 1
. . 1 1
;;;;
run;


%let vars=d_201409-d_201412;

data one_div_two;
  set one;    *dividend first, then divisor;
  array vars &vars.;
  array tempstore[1000] _temporary_;  *1000 is arbitrary, something large as or larger than &vars size;
  array tempsums[1000] _temporary_;  *same idea;
    do _i = 1 to dim(vars);  *store dividend in temporary array;
    tempstore[_i] = vars[_i];
  end;
  set two;
  do _i = 1 to dim(vars);  *now we divide original number by stored dividend;
    vars[_i] = 1000 * divide(vars[_i],tempstore[_i]);
    tempsums[_i] = sum(tempsums[_i],vars[_i]);       *store away the running total;
    vars[_i] = tempsums[_i];                         *and retrieve it;
  end;
run;



proc means data=one_div_two noprint;   *and we summarize.  Could do this in the above step too, but easier here.;
  var &vars.;
  output out=id_Summ sum=;
run;
```

Comment: how do I see in the dataset to check if it is working fine?

Comment: Open it?  `PROC PRINT` it?

Comment: I just updated with an example I am not sure if this is what it is performing

Comment: Your example doesn't look like it really matches your question.  What's with all the blanks?

Comment: Those missing ones are ideally 0.I can use this `proc stdize out=zeros reponly missing=0;
run;`

Comment: Sure, but then you're dividing by zero.

Comment: zero  by something ideally not dividing by zero

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146272/discussion-between-viji-and-joe).